# Jquery cookie in Tabs: Keep or change class on previously active tab?

Tags: jquery, cookies, addclass, removeclass

When I click on a tab, the class "defaulttab" is attached to active tab. But, when I refresh the page, the tab that I was last on loses that class, and the class defaults to the original tab. How can I refresh the page, and keep the class attached to the tab that was previously active?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.tabs a').click(function(){
         switch_tabs(jQuery(this));
    });
    switch_tabs(jQuery('.defaulttab'));
});

function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    jQuery('.tab-content').hide();
    jQuery('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");
    jQuery('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("active"); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery tabs with cookie - If cookie exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804217/jquery-tabs-with-cookie-if-cookie-exists)